# I am not able to connect express.js with react

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

I have include "Proxy": "http://localhost:8080"

But I am still geting below error :

> POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Have you included proxy in the frontend's `package.json`? Because it seems like you included it in backend's